# Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, union

I have looked over my code and I can't find the error. What is confusing, is that if I remove any one of the variables from the $stmt->bind_result() the above error does not occur, however; I obviously have problems further in the program as it can't find the deleted variable. It does find the one variable that is still kept in the bound result. This seems to be telling me that that there is only one result expected, yet I am asking for 2.

I have tried various ways to try and overcome the error, and to describe a little further, I am trying to obtain 2 different values to see if either one of the values have been already taken. They will generally occur in different rows but different columns of the same table, or at times not found at all in one or the other or both fields.

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT field_number FROM `fields` WHERE field_number = ?
            UNION ALL
            SELECT field_name FROM `fields` WHERE field_name = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("is", $f_number, $f_name);

$stmt->execute(); // execute the prepared query

$stmt->store_result(); // transfer the result set from the prepared statement

$stmt->bind_result($field_number, $field_name);

if($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
{
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $field_number;
        $field_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: That query will return a single column, probably named `field_number` rather than 2 distinct columns

Comment: `$stmt->affected_rows` are for checking how many rows an INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query affected. If you want to know how many rows a SELECT query found/returned, use `$stmt->num_rows` instead.

Comment: I don't know why all PHP tutorials seem to think that you need to count rows before you fetch them. You can just fetch them at once.

Answer (score 0):

That SQL only returns one column of data, which can originate from either table. That's how `union` works.

If you wanted to output *both* fields of any matching record -- so where either the number or the name matched, or both -- then don't use `union`, but select the two fields in one `SELECT` clause and make the condition an `OR`:

```sql
SELECT field_number, field_name FROM `fields` 
WHERE field_number = ? OR field_name = ?
```

If instead you want to output only the individual `field_number` or `field_name` that match, then you cannot expect them to be in pairs. There could be 10 `field_number` matches and only 3 `field_name` matches. If you then still want to know whether a match is a `field_number` or a `field_name`, then you should just perform two separate queries: one to find matching `field_number` and one to find matching `field_name`.

Comment: I have tried this method first and found that although it does return 2 values, they are generally in the same row. If it finds the field_number first, it returns the field_number and field_name from the same row as it is an or statement and both fields can be found in both rows. In my case, they could at times occur in the same row, but mostly not.

Comment: So explain this to me: you want to output 2 values each time (a number and a name), but then you assume there are just as many numbers as names that match... because you always want to output them in pairs. Can you edit your question and provide an example of input data (your two tables) and the expected output for them?

Comment: Each field_name has a unique field_number which is the given name and number of the football field, There are a number of football fields that exist, however; at some point in time, the name of the football field may change, or the unique field_number for that football field. In order not to have duplicate football field names, or duplicate football field numbers, I need to first check if either the field_name or the field_number already exist. Too Long - Second Part to follow on:

Comment: Second-Part: This being the case, it could be that the field_number may already exist in one row, and the field_name already exist in a different row as possibilities. These are all typographical errors that could occur when trying to make a change.

Comment: Please, can you edit your question and provide an example of input data (your two tables), then the values you will look for, and the expected output for them?